# Checking Pygame Version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm very new to both Python and Pygame. I have ***Python 3.5.1 32-bits*** installed on Window and ***Pygame 1.9.2 Python 3.5*** installed as well. But in case if I forget, is there a way to check the pygame version I have installed from either command line or Python IDLE.

For Python, I use **`python -V`**
But for Pygame, I don't know how to.

Comment: Oh man, I remember back when I installed pygame, last year. Such a hassle. If you search around you might find some cmd commands for finding the version i think.

Comment: Yeah. Such a devil. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this: `pip show <pack_name>`

Alternative:

```
pip freeze | grep <pack_name>
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is a year old and has an accepted answer but I've stumbled upon another way to check the version while researching.
You basically import pygame from the command line and type this code

```
pygame.version.ver
```

or

```
pygame.version.vernum
```

The first one returns the version as a string and the second one returns it as a tuple of integers.

I found this from [here](http://www.poketcode.com/pygame/versions/index.html)
and I know this might be unnecessairy but I wanted to include it anyway.

Comment: I needed a way to check from within the script and this does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
pip show pygame   // command to check your pygame details
```

output:

```
Name: pygame
Version: 1.9.4
Summary: Python Game Development
Home-page: https://www.pygame.org
Author: Pete Shinners, Rene Dudfield, Marcus von Appen, Bob Pendleton, others...
Author-email: pygame@seul.org
License: LGPL
Location: /home/linux/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```